# jQuery: How to check if images have finished loading in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some suggestion on how to work this around.

I have an Ajax code to execute when the LInk is clicked in my page. The ajax code is to call the PHP code to query the images(thumbnail size) filename inside a certain directory. Once executed, the ajax data will have the filenames of my thumbnails in that directory and display the thumbnails in my page dynamically.

I want to know any suggestion how to check if all thumbnails are already finished loading without using the SetTimeOut()? and execute some jquery codes once all thumbnails are loaded. I need my thumbnails to be loaded so I can set the size of my thumbnails div for scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method:

```
function imagesLoaded(imgAr, callback){
    var 
        // This is a copy of the array of images
        imageAr = imgAr.slice(0),
        // This holds the javascript Image Objects
        images = [],
        // This is the number of Images that has loaded
        loadedCount = 0;

    var imageLoaded = function(){
        // An image has finished loading, so increment the number of images loaded by 1
        loadedCount++;
        if(loadedCount>=imageAr.length){
            // If all images have finished loading, run the 'callback' function, to report back that images have all loaded
            callback.call();
        }
    }

    // Loop around each image url
    for(var i=0;i<imageAr.length;i++){
        // For each image, create a new object
        images[i] = new Image();
        // when the image finishes loading, call the imageLoaded function
        images[i].onload = imageLoaded;
        // Assign the image the appropriate src attribute
        images[i].src = imageAr[i];
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var imageAr = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'];

imagesLoaded(imageAr, function(){
    alert('Images loaded!');
});
```

Comment: HI jeztems, sorry for my ignorance. What's the purpose of this? "callback.apply({}, []);" . Is this the actual code? to be put in this line?

Comment: Yes it is mean't to be in the code, I have edited the origonal post to better explain what is going on. In this case "callback.apply({}, [])" means the exact same as "callback()", you can read more about apply here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

You could use **load** method for the images, like:

```
$('someElement img').load(function(){
  //all loaded
});
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: i've tried this already but doesnt seem to work on my requirements. Tnx