# Call function on image load

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery cycle plugin to create a simple slideshow with thumbnails.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/slideshow/

The thumbnails are in a sticky footer that stays at the bottom of the window.

I want the slideshow image to fill the rest of the window.

On the window resize I'm calling this function to resize the image

```
function resizeImg() {
  $('#slideshow img').css({'height':$('#wrap').height()-footerHeight,'width':'auto'});
}
```

My problem is when the image first loads it doesn't fill the space and is it's original size.

How can I call the resizeImg function when the image loads.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Title of the document</title>
      <!--jQuery-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle.js"></script>
      <!--CSS-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        ul{
          list-style:none;
        }
        /**/
        html, body {
            height:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #wrap {
            margin:auto;
            min-height:100%;
            margin-top:-100px;
            text-align:left;
        }
        * html #wrap {
            height:100%
        }
        #header {
            background:red;
            border-top:100px solid #fff; 
        }
        #footer {
            background:#eee;
            margin:auto;
            height:100px;
            clear:both;
        }
        /**/
        #slideshow img{
          margin:0 0 0 55px;
          height:100%;
        }

        div#thumbWrap {
          position: relative;
          height: 100px;
          width: 500px;
          overflow: auto;
          margin:0 0 0 50px;
        }
        ul#thumbs {
          display: block;
          width: 2000px;
          padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
        }
        ul#thumbs li {
          display: block;
          float: left;
          padding: 0 4px;
        }
        ul#thumbs a {
          display: block;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul#thumbs img {
          border: 3px #fff solid;
        }
        ul#thumbs a:hover img {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">

        </div><!-- #header -->
        <div id="slideshow">
          <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="" />
        </div><!-- #content -->
      </div><!-- #wrap -->

      <div id="footer">
          <div id="thumbWrap">
            <ul id="thumbs">

            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function() { 

          $("#slideshow img").load(function () { 
            alert('here');
          })

          resizeImg();
          /*-cycle
          */
          $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
              fx:     'fade', 
              speed:  'fast', 
              timeout: 0, 
              pager:  '#thumbs', 
              before: resizeImg(),

              pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                  return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="auto" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
              } 
          });
          /*-thumbnailScroll
          */
          var div = $('div#thumbWrap'), ul = $('ul#thumbs'), ulPadding = 15;
          var divWidth = div.width();
          div.css('overflow','hidden');
          var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');
          div.mousemove(function(e){   
            var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;        
            var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;         
            div.scrollLeft(left);         
          });

          var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();

          function resizeImg() {
            $('#slideshow img').css({'height':$('#wrap').height()-footerHeight,'width':'auto'});
          }

          $(window)
            .scroll(resizeImg)
            .resize(resizeImg)
            .onload(resizeImg)
        });

      </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: A very simple function I recently wrote for another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509694/jquery-how-to-check-if-images-have-finished-loading-in-ajax/10509808#10509808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a frustrating problem that I've dealt with in the past as well. Different browsers load images differently.

The easiest solution I've used is to just use the [jQuery.imagesLoaded plugin](http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/), which may do the job for you as well.